# Appended files to FormData not received at Laravel server

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, xmlhttprequest

I'm facing a strange issue ... I've a form with multiple fields .. on form submit, I append multiple image files to form data and submit it like this:

```
            $('#newEntry').on('submit', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                const formData = new FormData(e.target);

                formData.delete('images[]');

                for (var i = 0; i < filesToUpload.length; i++) {
                    formData.append('images[]', filesToUpload[i].file, filesToUpload[i].file.name);
                }
                $(this)[0].submit();
            });
```

and when I try to `echo(count($request->images))` at Laravel server it echos `0` .. and on `dd($request)` .. I see empty files array

but when I submit same form with same files directly from `input` field instead of appending data to it like this:

```
<input type="file" name="images[]">
```

I receive all files at server.

Files are successfully appended to `formData` .. I've checked it by:

```
                var formKeys    = formData.keys();
                var formEntries = formData.entries();

                do {
                  console.log(formEntries.next().value);
                } while (!formKeys.next().done)
```

I've also tried to send same appended files through `AJAX` and it worked perfectly fine:

```
             $('#newEntry').on('submit', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                const formData = new FormData(e.target);

                formData.delete('images[]');

                for (var i = 0; i < filesToUpload.length; i++) {
                    formData.append('images[]', filesToUpload[i].file, filesToUpload[i].file.name);
                }

                $.ajax({
                    url: actionURL,
                    data: formData,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("DONE");
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert("ERROR - " + data.responseText);
                    }
                });
             });
```

on digging down deeper .. I've found that when I submit a form via Http request an Error with code 500 Internal Server Error appears in console for a moment (just before page reloads)

tried everything but don't know what is causing this strange behavior .. kindly help me sort it out

Comment: did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax

Comment: Can you submit the internal 500 error from log please?

Comment: I can't find anything in laravel logs, apache logs or php error logs .. where to find this error?

Comment: @ChamaraAbeysekara your provided link solves the AJAX issue. In my case, AJAX is working correctly, I'm having issues with normal Http Request

Comment: I did you mean normal form submit? check whether you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form tag

Comment: @ChamaraAbeysekara yes it is there

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `network` tab of your browser(Preferably `Chrome`) to compare the request parameters that you send to the server.

If the request is too fast that you can't capture it, try placing `debugger;`(Or click on the in front of the line of code in the source tab) into your Javascript code to stop the execution of the code right before it reload. Then you can inspect the current state of your Javascript and also the `500` response that you received.